# /bin/bash: scripts/script.sh: Permission denied

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric

I am testing how to install a sample network for Hyperledger Fabric. when I was running 'byfn.sh' inside the 'first-network' project, the console will prompt such error:

> /bin/bash: scripts/script.sh: Permission denied

it looks like this line produces above error:

> docker exec cli scripts/script.sh $CHANNEL_NAME $CLI_DELAY $LANGUAGE $CLI_TIMEOUT $VERBOSE

I used root user, and have used **chmod +x** or **u+x** to change all *.sh files permission. but doesn't work, so any ideas? many thanks!!

Comment: So, you want to execute 'scripts/script.sh' inside a running container named 'cli'? Which user does the running container use? See `docker inspect -f '{{.Config.User}}'` or use `docker exec --user root cli scripts/script.sh`. If it needs interactive terminal then `docker exec -it --user root cli scripts/script.sh`

Comment: No, it doesn’t work

Comment: Would chown be appropriate here?

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I solved this problem by myself.

use Set SELinux mode as permissive:

> $ setenforce 0
>
> $ docker exec -it cli bash

the detailed solution is below:
https://nanxiao.me/en/selinux-cause-permission-denied-issue-in-using-docker/

I have no idea why it happens, but I hope if it can help someone.

Comment: Having the answer on an external site is of marginal value.

Comment: I searched for the answer a whole night, to be honest, I give the link to external what I found instead just copy a simple answer, but it's not intended to advertise

Comment: I suggest putting the answer here, with a link giving credit to where you found it. That way, even if the external link disappears, the answer is here, without someone having to click to see what the answer is.

Answer (score -1):

Use sudo when running the command, will solve the issue.